# Get only one package from 11.10 to install on 11.04

Tags: 11.10, backport

I need one really important package from oneiric to be installed (upgraded) on natty.

How can I extract just single deb file? (64 bit).

Should I use backports? if yes, can you please tell me how to set the backports from oneiric?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is not good idea. Oneiric is still alpha version and many packages are broken or unstable. You can also have many problems with dependecies.

Which package do you need? Maybe there is a PPA with newer version.

General howto for backports -- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBackports

Comment: yes normally this may be dangerous however I think that in my case this would cause any issues. The package is: xserver-xorg-video-openchrome. The one I'm trying to get i: xserver-xorg-video-openchrome_0.2.904+svn920-1

Answer (score 5):

While I stress that this *probably* isn't a good idea, [you can download the package you mentioned in the comment here.](http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/xserver-xorg-video-openchrome)

Download it for your specific system ([i386](http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/i386/xserver-xorg-video-openchrome/download) or [amd64](http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/amd64/xserver-xorg-video-openchrome/download))

Then, to install it, run the following:

`sudo dpkg -i <path-to-.deb>` in a Terminal.

Please, again, this is likely to break things, because this is a `xserver` level package.

Comment: yes, but in this case no worries. It's related to display driver for VIA chipsets only. THANK YOU!

Comment: Alright fair enough. You're welcome. :)