# How to install package from newer distribution?

Tags: 10.04, package-management

I have Ubuntu 10 server and want to update a package to newer version (update rrdtool from 1.3.8 to current 1.4.5). What should I do? Download and build sources or get package from newer distribution? And how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

#### Current package versions

Unfortunately [`rrdtool 1.4.5`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/rrdtool) has still not been packed for Ubuntu. Even Ubuntu's Precise `rrdtool` version is still [version 1.4.3](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rrdtool).

That can of course change in the recent future so keep an eye open, probably the latest version can be applied before the release of Ubuntu 12.04.

In the mean while if you want to install Ubuntu's 12.04 version you can do so by changing the version package you want to install, for more information about this visit this page:

- [Ubuntu's general backports wiki
  page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBackports)

And for for information on how to install a single package visit this post

- [Get only one package from 11.10 to install on 11.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57793/get-only-one-package-from-11-10-to-install-on-11-04)

It will give you an idea of the risks and guide you trough the installation of the package.

#### Compiling from source

You can of course still use version 1.4.5 from the `rrdtool` from it's [official website](http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/download.en.html) and compile it for your system.

For that please refer to the documentation for compiling it, it is included on the `rdtool` website

- [How to compile `rdtool` for in your
  system](http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/doc/rrdbuild.en.html)

Answer (score 1):

If at all possible it is best to use your package manager rather then install from source.

See this discussion for details (it is written for Fedora by applies all the same)

https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Package_management_system

I would try to use a ppa

https://launchpad.net/~jdub/+archive/ppa/+packages

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jdub/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rrdtool
```